# synthetic procedure for 1,3,4 thiadiazole from acylhydrazide

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, heterocyclic-compounds, medicinal-chemistry

I wanted to synthesize 1,3,4 thiadiazole-2- thiol substituted to  benzoic acid the reaction has to happen in such a way that the "acid hydrazide" group of benzoic acid hydrazide has to undergo cyclization in presence of carbon disulfide to form 1,3,4-thiadiazole is their any way to carry out the synthesize

Answer (score 1):

2 steps:- react the acylhydrazide and carbon disulfide with KOH in EtOH then acidify the resulting potassium salt with sulfuric acid which causes spontaneous cyclisation to the required product as reported in this [review](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/cr400131u) from which I have taken the reaction scheme (top line applies).

[image]

Comment: i tried this procedure by stirring overnight and also tried heating with reflux but my acyl hydrazide derivative not dissolving in the first step

Comment: What solvents is it soluble in? THF, dioxane, iPrOH?

Comment: the basic nucleus is showing solubility in ethanol

Comment: @Dina obvious question, but did you go to the review, find the original paper it referenced and follow the procedure from there?